# check in php html word

Tags: php, html

How can i check in PHP if a word exists in this website "url" or not.

For example, i have 4 sites that i want to check if the word **"asus"** exits in all of those sides of not and if exits count them !!

```
www.google.com
www.apple.com
www.microsoft.com
www.asus.com
```

i have tried in different different ways but no luck !!

How can i do that if PHP, DO ANYONE KNOWS !!!

I have search a lot but don't have the idea how to do that !!

Can someone please help me with this please

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to make a get request to each, then check the returned source for the string.

Comment: Google gave me around 30 websites which perfectly explain what you want, so Im actually curious what you googled..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)** function which is used to find the occurrence of one string inside other:

```
if (strpos($url,'word') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

*Source: [How do I check if a string contains a specific word in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words)*

To find a word in a complete webpage use **file_get_contents**

```
$text = file_get_contents('http://www.url.com/');
echo (stristr ($text, 'word')) ? 'found' : 'not found';
```

Comment: i actaully wanted to check on the webpage if the word exists or not !!!

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

```
$url1 = 'www.google.com';
$url2 = 'www.apple.com';
$url3 = 'www.microsoft.com';
$url4 = 'www.asus.com';

$word = 'asus';

if (strpos($url1, $word) !== false && strpos($url2, $word) !== false && strpos($url3, $word) !== false && strpos($url4, $word) !== false) {
    echo "$word Exist";
}else{
    echo "$word Not Exist";
}
```

Hope this will help